# Intercity chef-repo Capistrano asking for deploy password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, chef-infra

I have set up a vps everything according to the https://github.com/intercity/chef-repo instructions. I have set up Capistrano but when i try cap production deploy:check

it keeps asking for deploy password. But i don't have one because it is generated through the intercity node. I have the public key of my server in the node file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you can log in via normal SSH manually. Guessing you didn't get the SSH keys installed correctly.